# JavaFX PrinterJob prints random characters instead of regular text

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to print an invoice (AnchorPane) which has a number of Labels, GridPanes, VBox, etc containing invoice information. Aside from the fact that the scaling is all messed up, I'm only able to print random characters instead of the invoice information.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something or doing something wrong but I can't figure it out. All help is much appreciated.

code used for printing below:

```
Printer defaultPrinter = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

    // Create a printer job for the default printer
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (job != null)
    {

        // Print the node
        boolean printed = job.printPage(ap_invoice);

        if (printed)
        {
            // End the printer job
            System.out.println("Print Job Successful");
            job.endJob();
        }
        else
        {
            // Write Error Message
            System.out.println("Print Job Faild);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No one has any ideas about this topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this on OS X when using the "System" font, which is a JavaFX-specific thing.  I switched to using "Verdana" (i.e., a font known by name to the OS) and the problem went away.